# appending list to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm not understanding the behavior of appending data to a dataframe.

what i want to do is append a list with two values like this:

```
temp_arr
[Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0]
```

to a dataframe with two columns.  However, its adding two rows, not one row with two columns:

```
df_final = df_final.append(pd.DataFrame(temp_arr),ignore_index=True)
```

produces something like this:

```
df_final.head()
0
0   2018-01-01 00:00:00
1   0
2   2018-01-02 00:00:00
3   0
4   2018-01-03 00:00:00
```

instead of something like this

```
df_final.head()

col1  col2
0     2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Try, `df_final = pd.concat([df_final, pd.DataFrame(temp_arr)], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @coldspeed nope, got the same results - does it have something to do with the fact I'm using a timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col1', 'col2'])
temp_arr = [pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0]
df.append(pd.Series(temp_arr, index = ['col2', 'col1']),ignore_index=True)
```

You get

```
    col1    col2
0   0   2018-01-01
```

Comment: this doesn't work.  running your code for me produces an empty dataframe.  Also, pd.Series produces one column - I want to essentially two columns to a dataframe

Comment: Can you share more details, how are you creating the empty data frame? Because it works for me

Comment: my error it works now.  Can you explain the behavior of the Series in your code? i thought index sets an index for ***rows*** not ***columns*** as in this case

Comment: When you append a data frame to another data frame, it maps the column names. Whereas when you append a series to the dataframe, it maps the indices of the series with that of columns of the dataframe